# Does there exist a bijection from any infinite positive collection of integers to the natural numbers.

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions, elementary-set-theory

I was curious about the following "problem"

Gven an infinite set of positive integers where each element appears exactly once does there exist a  bijection to the natural numbers.

Now my intuition is that the statement is true. But I do not now if I can simple conclude it to be true since it is a infinte subset of the set with least infinite cardinality.

So I tried to use the idea of constructing a function (more precisly a bijective function) $f:N\to S$ where $S$ is the aforementiond set of positive integers . And my idea was to use the well ordering principle to inductivly (I guess) define the function.

So let $M(X)$ denote the least element of the set $X$ (this is possible if $X$ is non empty set of positive integers).

Define $f$ as

$f(1)=M(S)$

$f(2)=M(S \backslash M(S))$

$f(n)=M(S\backslash(M(S)\cup M(S\backslash M(S)) \cup...\cup M(S\backslash M(S\backslash M(S)...)$

The last should read the n:th least element of $S$. With this function I think the injective condition should follow immediatly. But the surjective condition is what makes me doubt the construction as a function. Since for any element $a\in S$ we must know where $a$ is which does not seem possible if we are not allowed to pair each element appearing before $a$ in the list which  in of it self seems doubtful.

So my questions is

1. Does every infinite set of positive integers have the same cardniality as the natural numbers
2. Is my construction "$f$" a working function or is it trivial and nondescriptive

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the statment is correct. And so is your idea about how to prove it. But it is simpler to express it as follows:$$f(n)=\begin{cases}\min S&\text{ if }n=1\\\min(S\setminus\{f(1),f(2),\ldots,f(n-1)\})&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 0):

Your function seems alright, altough there are simpler ways to write it. However, Professor José Carlos Santos already answered that nicely.

I'll just add that surjectivity comes easily by induction, as it is inductive itself.

Clearly the smallest element in $S$ is the image of $1$.

Now assume that the image of the first $n$ naturals are your smallest $n$ elements.

Then the $n+1$-th smallest element is $\min(S\setminus\{f(1),\ldots,f(n)\})$ (using the Professor's definition here), so it's $f(n+1)$. Result follows by induction.

Comment: Sadly I can not accept two answers, your contribution helped me aswell!